# Issue with npm sleep package while upgrading to Node 6

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm attempting to upgrade my project to Node 6.1.0 but I'm getting this error in the npm sleep package when I attempt to npm install:

```
> sleep@3.0.1 install 
> node-gyp rebuild

gyp WARN download NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR is deprecated and will be removed in node-gyp v4, please use NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR
gyp WARN download NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR is deprecated and will be removed in node-gyp v4, please use NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR
gyp WARN download NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR is deprecated and will be removed in node-gyp v4, please use NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR
CXX(target) Release/obj.target/node_sleep/sleep.o
In file included from ../sleep.cc:2:0:
../../nan/nan.h:602:20: error: variable or field ‘AddGCEpilogueCallback’ declared void
   v8::Isolate::GCEpilogueCallback callback
                ^
../../nan/nan.h:602:7: error: ‘GCEpilogueCallback’ is not a member of ‘v8::Isolate’
   v8::Isolate::GCEpilogueCallback callback
   ^
../../nan/nan.h:603:18: error: expected primary-expression before ‘gc_type_filter’
 , v8::GCType gc_type_filter = v8::kGCTypeAll) {
              ^
../../nan/nan.h:608:20: error: variable or field ‘RemoveGCEpilogueCallback’ declared void
   v8::Isolate::GCEpilogueCallback callback) {
                ^
../../nan/nan.h:608:7: error: ‘GCEpilogueCallback’ is not a member of ‘v8::Isolate’
   v8::Isolate::GCEpilogueCallback callback) {
   ^
../../nan/nan.h:613:20: error: variable or field ‘AddGCPrologueCallback’ declared void
   v8::Isolate::GCPrologueCallback callback
                ^
../../nan/nan.h:613:7: error: ‘GCPrologueCallback’ is not a member of ‘v8::Isolate’
   v8::Isolate::GCPrologueCallback callback
   ^
../../nan/nan.h:614:18: error: expected primary-expression before ‘gc_type_filter’
 , v8::GCType gc_type_filter = v8::kGCTypeAll) {
              ^
../../nan/nan.h:619:20: error: variable or field ‘RemoveGCPrologueCallback’ declared void
   v8::Isolate::GCPrologueCallback callback) {
                ^
../../nan/nan.h:619:7: error: ‘GCPrologueCallback’ is not a member of ‘v8::Isolate’
   v8::Isolate::GCPrologueCallback callback) {
   ^
make: *** [Release/obj.target/node_sleep/sleep.o] Error 1
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: For some reason pre-installing sleep with `npm install sleep` before `npm install` makes this work but I don't understand why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Needed to upgrade babel-cli to 6.10.1 in order to get the change made here: https://github.com/babel/babel/commit/f81d9e1274ffeb8b558603e74d771e6f84a9b0d5, preventing chokidar and then fsevents from trying to install in non-mac environments.